# Pointers pointing contiguous memory

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

Consider the following code

```
struct foo
{
    const int txt_len;
    const int num_len;

    char * txt;
    int * num;

    foo(int tl, int nl): txt_len(tl), num_len(nl)
    {
        char * tmp = new char[txt_len * sizeof(char) + num_len * sizeof(int)];

        txt = new (tmp) char [txt_len * sizeof(char)];
        num = new (tmp + txt_len * sizeof(char)) int[num_len * sizeof(int)];

        // is this the same as above?
        // txt = tmp;                                  
        // num = (int *) (tmp + txt_len * sizeof(char));
    }

    ~foo()
    {
        delete[] txt; // is this the right way to free the memory?
    }
};
```

I want `*txt` and `*num` to be contiguous, is that the best way to do it?

also is there any difference between placement new and pointer arithmetic? which one should I use?

Comment: I had no idea you could use new on existing memory that way. +1 for you.

Comment: It's hard to give you a useful answer without understanding why you want contiguous memory. It really depends on what you plan to do with it. (For example, do you plan to dereference pointers to it? If so, of what type? Do you want the spacing a normal structure will have? Or do you want it packed?) Your code above is illegal, you cannot pass placement new a pointer that is not aligned.

Comment: Put the `int` first, since it has the more stringent alignment requirement.  And `sizeof (char)` is guaranteed to be exactly `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a contiguous block of memory, you have to allocate it whole with a single call to `operator new[]` or `malloc()` or similar. Multiple calls to these functions do not guarantee any contiguity of allocated blocks whatsoever. You may allocate a big block and then carve parts from it as needed.

And you should `delete` and `free()` all blocks previously allocated with `new` and `malloc()`, otherwise you'll leak memory and probably make your program unstable (it will fail to allocate more memory at some point) and exert unnecessary pressure on memory in the OS, possibly slowing down other programs or making them unstable as well.

Placement new, however, does not actually allocate any memory. It simply constructs an object at the specified location and so you don't need to free that memory twice.

One problem that I see in your code is that it doesn't align ints. On some platforms reading or writing integers bigger than 1 byte from/to the memory must be aligned and if it's not, you can either read/write values from/to wrong locations or get CPU exceptions leading to termination of your program. The x86 is very permissive in this regard and won't mind, though may tax you with degraded performance.

Comment: I'm not sure what your point is. It appears that you are confirming that the OPs code is correct, apart from the alignment issue. Is this right?

Comment: OK, sorry. When I read the sentence with " ... you have to allocate it whole with a single call to operator new[] ... " I thought you meant that you thought that the OP had used multiple calls. But then it's clear you understand that only one of the OP's calls really allocates new memory. Thanks for that clarificatin.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the help, I didn't know about the alignment.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to put the int data first, due to the alignment issues. But we can't then do `delete num[]` as the type is wrong - it must be cast to a `char*` before deleting.

```
char * tmp = new char[num_len * sizeof(int) + txt_len * sizeof(char)];

num = new (tmp) int[num_len];
txt = new (tmp + num_len * sizeof(int)) char [txt_len];
```

(This makes liberal use of the fact that `sizeof(char)==1`)

You might be tempted to do `delete[] num`, but num is of type `int*`, and it was `new`'ed as a `char*`. So you need to do;

```
delete[] (char*) num;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as long as you use POD types. And your delete is fine.
However, as David's comment states, you need to consider alignment problems.

Comment: What if txt_len is 3 and integers have to be aligned on 4-byte boundaries on his platform?

Answer (score 0):

Placement new is mostly use when you want to call constructor of class/struct on some preallocated memory blocks.

But for native types it makes no different to use placement new & pointer arithmetic.

Please correct me if I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If txt and num always point to int and char, other built in types or other types not requiring construction, then no. You don't need placement new.

If on the other hand you were to change one of them to a class which requires construction, i.e. changes txt to type std::string, then using placement new is necessary.

Placement new allows you to call the constructor, building, if you like, the object at that address. Built in types have default constructors that do nothing if your not initializing.

In both cases you need to do pointer arithmetic, just one way you store the answer in a pointer, the other you pass the answer to placement new which gives it back to you for storage in the pointer, and then calls the constructor.